# Como chamar aba

Tags: materialize

Tenho um Navbar com algumas abas (tabs) que, caso seja clicado no link **INÍCIO** (por exemplo), abre uma div com as informações principais do site, caso o link clicado seja a **GALERIA**, então um novo conteúdo é trazido.

Houve uma necessidade de chamar essas abas também pelo Rodapé para facilitar a navegação do cliente, mas não estou conseguindo chamá-la.

Meu Navbar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<!-- NAVBAR -->
    <nav class="nav-extended deep-orange">

        <div class="nav-wrapper center">
            <img style="margin-top: 25px;" src="imagem/logo.png" alt="">
        </div>

        <!-- Abas -->
        <div class="nav-wrapper" style="padding: 0 10% 0 10%">
            <ul class="tabs tabs-transparent tabs-fixed-width">
                <li class="tab"><a href="#inicio" class="active">Início</a></li>
                <li class="tab"><a href="#galeria">Galeria</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>



    <!-- ABAS -->

    <!-- ABA INÍCIO -->
    <div id="inicio" class="col s12">
        <p>Início</p>
    </div>

    <!-- ABA GALERIA -->
    <div id="galeria" class="container">
       <p>Galeria</p>
    </div>
```

Meu rodapé, onde não está sendo possível chamar as abas pois não respondem, ou seja, ao clicar em **INÍCIO** ou em **GALERIA**, nada acontece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<footer class="page-footer deep-orange accent-4">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col l6 s12">
                <h5 class="white-text">Estamos sempre à disposição</h5>
                <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4">Precisa de algo que não encontrou em nosso site? Entre em contato conosco que faremos o possível para atendê-lo (a).</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col l4 offset-l2 s12">
                <h5 class="white-text">Menu</h5>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Início</a></li>
                    <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Galeria</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

O que tentei foram várias formas que vi em tutoriais, mas não funcionou provavelmente porque são já desatualizados as formas utilizadas. O teste padrão de chamar por id também não funcionou:

```
<li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#inicio">Início</a></li>
<li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#galeria">Galeria</a></li>
```

Comment: Cara o que seria "as abas não respondem" ? Qual versão do Materialize vc está usando? Não está muito claro o seu problema...

Comment: Descrevi melhor o problema, se puder dar uma olhada, agradeço. Versão do Materialize sendo utilizado: 1.0.0.

Comment: @DeividSouza para isso funcionar, é preciso também que o `ul` e o `li` tenha as classes de `tabs` e `tab` respectivamente. Porém, isso vai quebrar seu layout. Então, eu sugiro você criar uma função jQuery para cada item desse e a função dava um trigger nos links das tabs. Deu pra entender?

Comment: Cadê a resposta do Matheus?

Comment: Olha só, bem verdade. Vou cobrá-lo rs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<ul class="links-rodape">
   <li class="links"><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#inicio-tab">Início</a></li>
   <li class="links"><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#galeria-tab">Galeria</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
                $(document).ready(function() {

                    // Chamar links do Menu do rodapé 
                    $('.links-rodape > .links > a').on('click', function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        var tab = $(this).attr('href').replace('-tab', ''); // Remove o '-tab' do href
                        tab = tab.replace('#', '');

                        const navbar = $('#tabSelector').get(0);
                        M.Tabs.getInstance(navbar).select(tab);
                    });
                }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para isso funcionar, é preciso também que o ul e o li tenha as classes de tabs e tab respectivamente. Porém, isso vai quebrar seu layout. Então, eu sugiro você criar uma função jQuery para cada item desse e a função dava um trigger nos links das tabs.

Tipo assim:

Apenas atente-se aos `href`, coloque um '-tab' no nome para ficar diferente do `href` das tabs lá de cima.

```
<ul class="links-rodape">
   <li class="links"><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#inicio-tab">Início</a></li>
   <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#galeria-tab">Galeria</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.links-rodape > .links > a').on('click', function({
       var tab = $(this).attr('href').replace('-tab', ''); // Remove o '-tab' do href

       // Trigger
       $('a[href="'+tab+'"]').click();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia Deivid,

O mesmo código que você utilizou no navbar pode ser utilizado também no footer como "âncora" para poder ser levado até a sessão em que está disponível seu HTML.

Coloquei o código abaixo para você testar e ilustrar melhor o cenário:

```
<!-- ABAS -->

<!-- ABA INÍCIO -->
<div id="inicio" class="col s12" style="margin-bottom: 500px; margin-top: 200px;">
    <p>Início</p>
</div>

<!-- ABA GALERIA -->
<div id="galeria" class="container" style="margin-bottom: 800px;">
   <p>Galeria</p>
</div>

<footer class="page-footer deep-orange accent-4">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col l6 s12">
            <h5 class="white-text">Estamos sempre à disposição</h5>
            <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4">Precisa de algo que não encontrou em nosso site? Entre em contato conosco que faremos o possível para atendê-lo (a).</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col l4 offset-l2 s12">
            <h5 class="white-text">Menu</h5>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#inicio">Início</a></li>
                <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#galeria">Galeria</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Colocando dessa maneira, a única coisa que muda é no link, onde é acrescentado o id: gravata/index.php#galeria, mas a aba (ou tab) **INÍCIO** ou **GALERIA** não são chamados.

Comment: o que você está considerando como "chamar"? você testou o código que eu disponibilizei? Pois dessa forma, ele leva você até a sessão da mesma página que está com esse identificador.

Comment: Chamar =  ao clicar no link, leva você até a sessão da mesma página que está com esse identificador.

Comment: Tenho uma única página (o index.php) e utilizo tabs do Materialize. Quando clico no link GALERIA por exemplo e estou em INÍCIO, o conteúdo que está no link GALERIA é trazido (lembrando, tudo no mesmo index.php). Todos os links do cabeçalho funcionam normalmente, mas quando vou fazer o mesmo com menu no rodapé, esses links não dão sinal de vida, ou seja, não são chamados os respectivos conteúdos.

Comment: Então Deivid, pode ser algum outro trecho do seu código que está fazendo isso. Se você testar somente o trecho que te mandei, você vai ver que ele está levando você até a sessão destino.